# Ruby 1.9.3 unexpected File behavior under msys

Tags: ruby, msys

I'm trying to copy a file to `"/usr/bin"` using Ruby 1.9.3 with msys on Windows 7.  Msys will happily do it from it's bash-like shell - `$cp testscript.rb /usr/bin` does the trick.

But from within Ruby it's completely different, and `FileUtils.cp` to `/usr/bin` or `C:/usr/bin` both fail.  The problem seems to lie in how msys and Ruby handle the paths and they don't agree on this one.

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ pwd
/usr/bin
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/msysgit/bin"
```

And sure enough, `FileUtils.cp("testscript.rb", "C:/msysgit/bin")` works.
Here's my question: How can I either translate between these?? I know I want to move my file into `/usr/bin` and I can extrapolate to `C:/usr/bin`, but I don't know how to find out that it is really `C:/msysgit/bin`, and I can't just hardcode it because it needs to work not just on my setup.

I need a way to either (1) convince Dir and FileUtils and File to understand the paths the same way the msys shell does or (2) Know how to translate between them.

Has anyone else seen this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd assume there's a root/home dir for msys, no (MSYSDIR maybe)? Combined with http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion should be enough to get them converted correctly.

Comment: What does `File.expand_path("/usr/bin")` return?

Comment: I tried that - unfortunately just `"c:/usr/bin"`

Comment: MSYSDIR or equivalent is exactly what I need!  But it's not MSYSDIR :(

Comment: OK, it turns out there is `ENV['BIN']` which contains `"C:\msysgit\bin"` which I can make work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, and I don't understand why this question was voted down, can someone explain for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows under msys (but not under linux) there is `ENV['BIN']` which contains the path to the bin directory, in this case `"C:\msysgit\bin"`.  This is actually the same directory pointed at by /bin and /usr/bin in msys so it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in my opinion is to use
[`cygpath`](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html)

However as you can expect this is a Cygwin program and will require the Cygwin
dll, as can be seen here

```
$ ldd /bin/cygpath | grep /usr
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
```

If this works for you, you can download `cygpath` from one of
[Cygwin mirrors](http://sourceware.org/cygwin/mirrors.lst)

Example

[`box-soft.com/release/cygwin/cygwin-1.7.18-1.tar.bz2`](http://box-soft.com/release/cygwin/cygwin-1.7.18-1.tar.bz2)

After that it is very easy to convert, as you can see

```
$ cygpath C:/msysgit/bin
/usr/bin

$ cygpath -m /usr/bin
C:/msysgit/bin
```